# Do we need to reapply for a Schengen visa to go back to Spain or is our visa still valid?

Tags: visas, schengen, filipino-citizens

We are given Schengen visas (multiple entry/type C) from 01-04-2016 until 27-09-2016 with duration of stay of 90 days and Remarks: *VIS FAMILIAR UE/EEE/SUIZA*. With my daughter we entered Spain August 30, 2016 and returned to the Philippines September 23, 2016 without having obtained a residence card. We did not have a chance to process or apply for our residence card because we are running out of days.

The lawyer said it takes three months to process and advised us to apply for our residence card when we come back. We decided to go back immediately to the Philippines because my daughter begged us to continue her elementary grade and wanted to graduate as valedictorian, since she is a candidate for that title. She said it would only happen for once in her lifetime! The school only allows her 20 days absence.

Now we are planning to go back to Spain after graduation in April (2017) and my daughter is ready to continue her studies there and been granted her request to finished her elementary grade here in the Philippines.

Comment: I am not sure I completely follow but is it really "27-09-2016"? If the validity period has elapsed, then no the visa is not valid anymore. But given the facts you presented, it should not be too difficult to get another one.

Comment: Thanks pnuts!  But ,Im confused with the multiple entry in our visa .what does it mean ?Does it not related to be still valid our visa ? Since we in and out spain within the validity date ?

Comment: Multiple entry means that you can leave and reenter the Schengen area as many times as you like *before the visa expires.* With a single- or dual-entry visa, you can only enter the Schengen area one or two times. But once the expiration date has passed, the visa is useless, no matter how many times you've used it, or even if you never used it once.

Answer (score 1):

You need a new visa.

Maybe think of your 01-04-2016 until 27-09-2016 visa like train pass of the same period of validity - being multiple entry can be used as often as you wish within the two limits. Thereafter it is useless for travel.